# Why is my ZF2 MVC App Using PhpRenderer instead of FeedRenderer?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, atom-feed, uncaught-exception

I have a controller class that extends `Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController`. I want one of the action method to generate an atom feed.

I enabled the `ViewFeedStratagy` in module.config.php:

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'stratagies' => array(
            'ViewFeedStratagy',
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

And in my controller, the code looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Feed\Writer\Feed;
use Zend\View\Model\FeedModel;

class BlogController extends AbstractActionController
{
    // other action methods

    public function atomAction()
    {
        $feed = new Feed;
        // set feed data
        $feed->export('atom');

        $feedModel = new FeedModel();
        $feedModel->setFeed($feed);
        return $feedModel;
    }
}
```

And when I request the page I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message
'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render:
Unable to render template "blog/blog/atom";
resolver could not resolve to a file'
```

Why is it still trying to use `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` rather than `Zend\View\Renderer\FeedRenderer`?

Comment: Maybe because you wrote `stratgies` instead of `strategies` ?

Comment: Or maybe because your alternative strategy doesn't have precedence over the default strategy? You may want to detach the listeners from the default strategy.

Comment: that typoe would do it :)

Comment: Can you please answer your own question and mark it as accepted? Now this question is still answered while the solution is available.

Comment: But how do I mark it as answered if the solution is in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

`'strategies'`, not `'stratagies'` ;)

Also `'ViewFeedStrategy'`, not `'ViewFeedStratagy'`